# Twitter Integration getting error Failed to validate oauth signature and token

Tags: apex, http, httprequest

i am trying to implement twitter authorization in my salesforce app.in first step i am trying to get request token from twitter.here is my code :

```
   public String getTwitterReqToken(){

        String base_string = 'POST&';
                                  String state = getRandomNonce();  
        base_string += EncodingUtil.urlEncode(twitterReqToken,'UTF-8');
            String callback = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(returnUrl,'UTF-8');
                String timestamp = String.valueOf(DateTime.now().getTime()/1000);                  

        String param_string = 'oauth_callback='+callback+'&oauth_consumer_key='+twitterConsumerKey
                              +'&oauth_nonce='+state+'&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp='+timestamp
                              +'&oauth_version=1.0';
         param_string = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(param_string,'UTF-8');
         base_string += '&' + param_string ;                     
        System.debug('base string is '+base_string);
        Blob sig = Crypto.generateMac('HmacSHA1', Blob.valueOf(base_string), 
        Blob.valueOf(twitterConsumerSecret));                  
        String signature = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(EncodingUtil.base64encode(sig), 'UTF-8');
        System.debug('signature is'+ signature);    
        String header ='OAuth oauth_callback="'+callback+'",'
                  +'oauth_consumer_key="'+twitterConsumerKey+'",'
                  +'oauth_nonce="'+state+'",'
                  +'oauth_signature="'+signature+'",'
                  +'oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",'
                  +'oauth_timestamp="'+timestamp+'",'
                  +'oauth_version="1.0"';
                  Map<String,String> map1 =new Map<String,String>();
                  map1.put('Authorization',header);
                  map1.put('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        String bb = basicAuthCallout(twitterReqToken,map1,'','POST');
        System.debug(bb+'');
        return bb;

    }

public String basicAuthCallout(String endPoint,Map<String,String> header, String body,String method){

    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    //endPoint = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(endPoint,'UTF-8');
    if(body != null && body.length() > 0)
    endpoint=endpoint+'?'+body;
    req.setEndpoint(endPoint);
    req.setMethod(method);
    for( String x : header.keySet())
    req.setHeader(x,header.get(x));

    Http http = new Http();
    System.debug('=========== REQ BODY:'+endPoint);
    HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
    return res.getBody();

}
```

when i call method getTwitterReqToken .its giving me error "Failed to validate oauth signature and token" .i think i called this callout properly .can any one please point out why i am facing this issue ??

Answer (score 2):

code is almost correct.the only small change that i have to put is instead of twitterConsumerSecret i have to replace it with twitterConsumerSecret + '&'

so i have to chage this :

```
Blob sig = Crypto.generateMac('HmacSHA1', Blob.valueOf(base_string), 
        Blob.valueOf(twitterConsumerSecret));
```

with :

```
Blob sig = Crypto.generateMac('HmacSHA1', Blob.valueOf(base_string), 
        Blob.valueOf(twitterConsumerSecret + '&'));
```

and i get my request token.thanks.